# Inserting facebook user info into a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

Basically what i want to do is when the user allows an application he will automatically signup for my autoresponder list, so i need to pass the user name and email to the form and automatically submit the form.

Here is the first part when i get the user info:

```
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
      };
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
         if (response.session) {
         FB.api({
         method: "fql.query",
         query: "SELECT name,email FROM user WHERE uid = " + response.session.uid
            }
```

here is the form:

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="XXXXXXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="XXXXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou.htm?m=default" id="redirect_e96b2b57089ff7b9fbdbc6ac41355eed" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="XXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
</div>
<div id="af-form-XXXXXXXX" class="af-form"><div id="af-header-XXXXXXXX" class="af-header"><div class="bodyText"><p>&nbsp;</p></div></div>
<div id="af-body-XXXXXXXX" class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-22176678">Name: </label>
<div class="af-textWrap">
<input id="awf_field-22176678" type="text" name="name" class="text" value=""  tabindex="500" />
</div>
<div class="af-clear"></div></div>
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-22176679">Email: </label>
<div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-22176679" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501"  />
</div><div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer">
<input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="502" />
<div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=HGwsjMxsLOwM" alt="" /></div>
</form>
```

Now i don't really need all the form code because i don't even want it to show (invisible) and all the forms basically have the same inputs names (name="name", name="email")

so i just wanna enter the list name and pass the user's name and his email to the fields and auto submit it using PHP/JavaScript/Jquery.

There is already scripts which does that and i want to build one my self ;)

**EDIT: My friend just gave me this code:**

```
customar_formcode=customar_formcode.replace("{email}", user.email); 
                                customar_formcode=customar_formcode.replace("{name}", user.name);       
                        document.getElementById(\'inneraction\').innerHTML=customar_formcode;
                        document.getElementById(\'form_id\').submit();
```

he said the user.name and use.email need to be set from the fql first, honestly i don't understand what i need to do next, do i need to insert the code on the page anyway? do i need to post the form in some special javascript format? what does 'inneraction' means?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying this type of patch you may use FB registration........
for detailed information on FB registration see below link

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/